# imageWithRenderingMode doesn't work with setImageWithUrl (for tintColor)

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I can tint a UIImage in a UIImageView using :

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But when the image is initialized with AFNetworking's `setImageWithUrl` :

```
imageView = [imageView setImageWithUrl:url];
imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This has no effect, the image is displayed with original colors.

Tested on iOS 7+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has no effect because you are assigning the image to be fetched from the remote URL, which takes time and thus happens *later* - after your code has finished. Thus, this line does nothing:

```
imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

...because, at the time it runs, `imageView.image` is still `nil`.

Instead, use a networking command with a completion handler, and don't change the image rendering mode until the completion handler. In particular, what I would do is: First, *download* the image. Now (in the completion handler) derive the template image and assign it to the image view.

**EDIT**:

Another problem, based on your later comments, is that you seem not to understand what an image view is. It holds *one* image - the most recently assigned image. So your code is now behaving exactly as I would expect - the image view is displaying the template image, because that is the last image you assigned to it.

`imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` colors the non-transparent parts of the original image the tint color and that's all - and that is exactly what you are now seeing, so your code is working.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, but even with a callback I can't get both the image and the filter. What am I doing wrong ? I have edited my question.

Comment: What does "both the image and the filter" mean? I see no "filter". Perhaps you don't understand what setting the image of an image view does? It can't have two images at once, you know. The whole "filter" idea seems to be something you made up inside your own head... :) Perhaps it would help if you took a few steps back and explained what you are _ultimately_ trying to do - in another question. (And please comment here when you do, because I want to help with that one too.) But I believe I've answered _this_ question.

Comment: "Filter" is the tint color. I'm not trying to assign two images, there is two assignements in the code just to show that the first one displays the image, but if you do the same assignement with RenderingMode the image is not displayed, only the tint.

Comment: That is what an `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` _is_. It colors the non-transparent parts the tint color and that's all. Again I ask you what you are trying to do.

Comment: Aw sorry. Just trying to add a color filter with alpha on a image. Do I need two views for this ?

Comment: I don't understand the words "add a color filter with alpha on a image"... But you would probably use a CIFilter, wouldn't you?

Comment: Again I suggest to you that I have answered your original question.

Comment: Ok I thought CIFilter was overkill because I don't need to filter the image in itself. Indeed my question was not correctly asked, sorry for that. What I need would be done in TheGimp/Photoshop by opening an image, creating a new layer on top, filling this layer with a plain color, and reducing the opacity of this layer by 50%. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "by opening an image, creating a new layer on top, filling this layer with a plain color, and reducing the opacity of this layer by 50%." You can do that directly to an image programmatically in iOS, almost exactly as you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still reaches this question, my suggestion would be to use UIButton instead of UIImageView. Import "UIButton+AFNetworking.h" and setUserInteractionEnabled as "FALSE" for UIButton to make it behave like a UIImageView.

The reason behind this is to use "setTintColor" of a system UIButton which functions likely in the same way as imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

Check below code:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem]; // to use tint color property
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, btnWidth, btnHeight)];
[myButton setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[myButton setImageForState:UIControlStateNormal withURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```